# jquery JSON not parsing from jQ AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm fairly new to jQuery and my JSON data doesn't seem to be parsing the way i expect it to be.

So i've created my data by json_encode($var); in PHP and that seems to work fine:

```
{"id":"7","0":"7","ip":"86.152.117.159","1":"86.152.117.159","proxyip":"86.152.117.159","2":"86.152.117.159","ping":"1","3":"1","time":"03:39:17","4":"03:39:17"}{"id":"6","0":"6","ip":"86.152.117.159","1":"86.152.117.159","proxyip":"86.152.117.159","2":"86.152.117.159","ping":"1","3":"1","time":"03:36:20","4":"03:36:20"}
```

(This is being imported via jQuery's AJAX from a separate URL on the same-server/domain).

But when i use this code to try to import it:

```
$.ajax({url:"load.php",success:function(result){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            $(".response").html(obj.id);
        }});
```

and check my console, i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" which points to "line 1" in index.php - Note i'm not using an external JS file.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong and how i should go about fixing the issue so i can display  the data in a non-json form on the page (i.e in a table)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Here's my load.php file:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_db", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}

$update = "SELECT * FROM traffic";
foreach ($db->query($update) as $user) {
    echo json_encode($user);
}
```

Comment: can you post the content of $var

Comment: You're doing something wrong, as what you've posted isn't valid JSON, there's a missing comma, and the two objects aren't contained in anything, that's where the syntax error is. Are you adding together JSON strings on the server ?

Comment: Oh, you're just echoing the JSON strings in a loop, that won't work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `echo json_encode(...)` twice. Put all the results into an array, and encode that.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($db->query($update) as $user) {
    $result[] = $user;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Then in the Javascript, you'll need a loop to read them out:

```
$.ajax({url:"load.php",success:function(result){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        var ids = obj.map(function(el) {
            return el.id;
        });
        $(".response").html(ids.join(' '));
    }
});
```

Comment: I got the arguments to the callback wrong, try now.

Comment: Works! :) - I'll vote best answer after i try some more things with it :)

Comment: Top Answer!
Extra credit: How would i go about putting the data in a table?

Comment: Put something like `$("#tableID").append("<tr><td>"+el.id+"</td><td>"+el.someCol+"</td></tr>");` in the loop.

Comment: I did this long ago, I face myself with another issue - Since you seem like a GOD at this SO - Here's the link :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662513/clearinterval-not-working-correctly

Answer (score 2):

Your json is not valid, use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check that.

```
Parse error on line 12:
...   "4": "03:39:17"}{    "id": "6",   
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

You have two objects. There should either be only one of them or two in an array like `[{}, {}]`.

You should be able to echo everything at once like:

```
echo json_encode($db->query("SELECT * FROM traffic")->fetchAll());
```

Comment: My PHP did this with json_encode($var); how do i go about fixing this?

Comment: I guess you have a loop or something that outputs two objects instead of one but you'll have to post some more code...

Comment: I added my load.php code above! Would maybe just appending the braces manually work?
`"[" . json_encode($user) . "]";`

Comment: Edit: The above comment didn't work, looking at the code it's clear that i encoded them all separately using foreach, i'll try encoding the actual foreach statement instead.

Comment: So, this stops the error which is good, but i'm still get no results being returned: `$(".response").html(obj.id);`

Comment: The response should be an array now so you can't just access `id` like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `JSON.parse()` instead:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
```

Or better still, specify `dataType:'json'` and set json content-type in PHP and you do not have to parse any strings in JS:

```
    $.ajax({url:"load.php", dataType:'json', success:function(result){
        $(".response").html(result.id);
    }});
```

**CAUTION:**

Make sure your json is valid. In case you're using a loop in PHP it is better construct an associative array and then pass the array to `json_encode()` just once.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome developer tools console, I tried JSON.parse(''), and got the same error.

> 

```
JSON.parse('{"id":"7","0":"7","ip":"86.152.117.159","1":"86.152.117.159","proxyip":"86.152.117.159","2":"86.152.117.159","ping":"1","3":"1","time":"03:39:17","4":"03:39:17"}{"id":"6","0":"6","ip":"86.152.117.159","1":"86.152.117.159","proxyip":"86.152.117.159","2":"86.152.117.159","ping":"1","3":"1","time":"03:36:20","4":"03:36:20"}')
VM123:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

The problem is that you're sending two consecutive objects - `{"id":"7",...}` and `{"id":"6",...}`. When it finds the first close curly brace `}`, it expects EOF, so the second open curly brace `{` throws an Unexpected token SyntaxError.

The solution is to wrap the objects in a JSON array.

Try `echo json_encode($db->query($update));` in your PHP, without the loop.

In chrome developer tools, network tab, when you examine the Preview, you should see

> `[{"id":"7",...},{"id":"6",...}]`

(with the rest of your properties substituted for my ellipses).