# clearInterval() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

I've recently been trying to repeat a jQuery AJAX request every two seconds. PLEASE NOTE: I've looked at the other questions on SO and not of them seem to apply to my situation, i've also looked at the documentation.

Snippet:

```
else if (text == "load") {
        $(".response").text("working!");

        var traffic = function load() {
            $.ajax({url:"load.php",success:function(result){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                var ids = obj.map(function(el) {
                    return "<tr><td>" + el.id + "</td><td>" + el.ip + "</td><td>" + el.proxyip + "</td><td>" + el.ping + "</td><td>" + el.time + "</td></tr>";
                });

                $(".response").html("<table><tr><td><strong>ID</strong></td><td><strong>IPs</strong></td><td><strong>Proxy IP</strong></td><td><strong>Ping</strong></td><td><strong>Time</strong></td></tr>" + ids + "</table>");
            }});
        };

        var trafficInterval = setInterval(traffic, 2000);
```

To cancle the timeout, i check to see if the text is not equal to "load", if it isnt equal to load, i cancle the timeout

```
else {
        $(".response").text("'" + badCommand + "'" +" is not a valid command, type 'help' for a list of commands.");
        clearInterval(trafficInterval);
    }
```

HOWEVER, when i change the input of the textfield, the table will still load every two seconds, the timeout hasn't been cancled and i can't seem to see why.

Here's the whole function for people wondering

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(){
var text = $(this).val();
$(".log").text(text);

// Commands
if (text != "") {
    var badCommand = $("textarea").val();

    if (text == "help") {
        $(".response").html("Commands:<br/><span class='indent'>traffic -url|all</span><span class='indent'>google #search term</span><span class='indent'>youtube #search term</span><span class='indent'>portfolio</span>")
    } else if (text == "traffic") {
        $(".response").html('Live traffic from:<br/><table><tr><td><strong>IP</strong></td><td><strong>Proxy IP</strong></td><td><strong>Ping</strong></td><td><strong>Time</strong></td></tr><?php try { $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_db", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass); $sql = "SELECT * FROM traffic ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50"; foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) { echo "<tr>"; echo "<td class='details'>" . $row["ip"] . "</td>"; echo "<td class='details'>" . $row["proxyip"] . "</td>"; echo "<td class='details'>" . $row["ping"] . "</td>"; echo "<td class='details'>" . $row["time"] . "</td>"; echo "</tr>"; } $db = null; } catch(PDOException $e) { $e->getMessage(); } ?></tr></table>');
    } else if (text == "load") {
        $(".response").text("working!");

        var traffic = function load() {
            $.ajax({url:"load.php",success:function(result){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                var ids = obj.map(function(el) {
                    return "<tr><td>" + el.id + "</td><td>" + el.ip + "</td><td>" + el.proxyip + "</td><td>" + el.ping + "</td><td>" + el.time + "</td></tr>";
                });

                $(".response").html("<table><tr><td><strong>ID</strong></td><td><strong>IPs</strong></td><td><strong>Proxy IP</strong></td><td><strong>Ping</strong></td><td><strong>Time</strong></td></tr>" + ids + "</table>");
            }});
        };

        var trafficInterval = setInterval(traffic, 2000);

    } else {
        $(".response").text("'" + badCommand + "'" +" is not a valid command, type 'help' for a list of commands.");
        clearInterval(trafficInterval);
    }
}

if (text == "") {
    var noCommand = $("textarea").val();
    $(".response").text(" ");
}

// End Commands
```

});

FYI:

Putting the clearInterval(); AFTER the code stops it from working,
Putting the clearInterval(); BEFORE the code does nothing.

The clearInterval(trafficInterval); MUST be working because if i place it at the end of the first function, nothing happens when i type "load"

It's not the timer either, i tried it instead to automatically update whenever the mouse is moved and the exact same thing happens...

Comment: can you provide the full if-else if-else construct please?

Comment: Should the text == "traffic" piece contain PHP?

Comment: Yes. I've not bothered updating that to JSON yet. I'll remove the function and test. - Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping issue. The interval needs to be outside the scope of the event handler call:

```
var trafficInterval = null;
$("textarea").keyup(function(){
var text = $(this).val();
$(".log").text(text);

// Commands
if (text != "") {
    var badCommand = $("textarea").val();

    if (text == "help") {
        $(".response").html("Commands:<br/><span class='indent'>traffic -url|all</span><span class='indent'>google #search term</span><span class='indent'>youtube #search term</span><span class='indent'>portfolio</span>")
    } else if (text == "traffic") {
        $(".response").html('');
    } else if (text == "load") {
        $(".response").text("working!");

        var traffic = function load() {
            $.ajax({url:"load.php",success:function(result){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                var ids = obj.map(function(el) {
                    return "<tr><td>" + el.id + "</td><td>" + el.ip + "</td><td>" + el.proxyip + "</td><td>" + el.ping + "</td><td>" + el.time + "</td></tr>";
                });

                $(".response").html("<table><tr><td><strong>ID</strong></td><td><strong>IPs</strong></td><td><strong>Proxy IP</strong></td><td><strong>Ping</strong></td><td><strong>Time</strong></td></tr>" + ids + "</table>");
            }});
        };

        trafficInterval = setInterval(traffic, 2000);

    } else {
        $(".response").text("'" + badCommand + "'" +" is not a valid command, type 'help' for a list of commands.");
        clearInterval(trafficInterval);
    }
}

if (text == "") {
    var noCommand = $("textarea").val();
    $(".response").text(" ");
}

// End Commands
});
```

See fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/sLooj4on/ (can see polling fail in dev tools, stops when text is removed from input)

Comment: block statements like if-else to *not* introduce a scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements

Comment: @ConorReid I am pointing out that defining vars inside of a block statement defines them inside of the scope of the surrounding function, not the block. So this proposal should not make a difference.

Comment: Ah ok. Well, i never knew that! Thank you :) - Unfortunately i still have my issue :c

Comment: @ConorReid btw, no need to define badCommand, just use text :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without looking at the rest of the code, but your trafficInterval variable could be out of scope. Try initializing outside of the if/else statement

Comment: block statements like if-else to *not* introduce a scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements

Answer (score 0):

trafficInterval is only defined within the if statement. You're trying to clear it in the wrong scope. I still lack a bit of context here but you can try this:

```js
var trafficInterval;
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
      var text = $(this).val();
      $(".log").text(text);

      // Commands
      if (text != "") {
        var badCommand = $("textarea").val();

        if (text == "help") {
          $(".response").html("Commands:<br/><span class='indent'>traffic -url|all</span><span class='indent'>google #search term</span><span class='indent'>youtube #search term</span><span class='indent'>portfolio</span>")
        } else if (text == "traffic") {
          $(".response").html('Live traffic from:<br/><table><tr><td><strong>IP</strong></td><td><strong>Proxy IP</strong></td><td><strong>Ping</strong></td><td><strong>Time</strong></td></tr><?php try { $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_db", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass); $sql = "SELECT * FROM traffic ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50"; foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) { echo "<tr>"; echo "<td class='
            details '>" . $row["ip"] . "</td>"; echo "<td class='
            details '>" . $row["proxyip"] . "</td>"; echo "<td class='
            details '>" . $row["ping"] . "</td>"; echo "<td class='
            details '>" . $row["time"] . "</td>"; echo "</tr>"; } $db = null; } catch(PDOException $e) { $e->getMessage(); } ?></tr></table>');
        } else if (text == "load") {
          $(".response").text("working!");

          var traffic = function load() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "load.php",
              success: function(result) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                var ids = obj.map(function(el) {
                  return "<tr><td>" + el.id + "</td><td>" + el.ip + "</td><td>" + el.proxyip + "</td><td>" + el.ping + "</td><td>" + el.time + "</td></tr>";
                });

                $(".response").html("<table><tr><td><strong>ID</strong></td><td><strong>IPs</strong></td><td><strong>Proxy IP</strong></td><td><strong>Ping</strong></td><td><strong>Time</strong></td></tr>" + ids + "</table>");
              }
            });
          };

          trafficInterval = setInterval(traffic, 2000);

        } else {
          $(".response").text("'" + badCommand + "'" + " is not a valid command, type 'help' for a list of commands.");
          clearInterval(trafficInterval);
        }
      }

      if (text == "") {
        var noCommand = $("textarea").val();
        $(".response").text(" ");
      }

      // End Commands
```

Comment: No idea, same error - It just doesn't seem to want to cancle the load after it's been entered.

Comment: Your solution works, but it is *not* the scope if the if statement but the event handler functions scope that is the culprit.

Comment: This code breaks the script completely. I can't type in the input box after copy&pasting this. Would you like the website link?

Answer (score 0):

Move the variable declaration

```
var trafficInterval = null;
```

before the keyup eventhandler (to move it to the outside scope). See working, stripped down example here:

http://jsbin.com/yitiquwoce/1/

Comment: Doesn't work. Same thing. Your cutdown version works, when edited to suit the script it does nothing different.

Comment: Infact, your cutdown version doesn't work either: No idea.
http://gyazo.com/1208ae319e2e955c5c1cec60f11ad9a6

Comment: @ConorReid The jsbin example works consistently. Reason: If you move the var declaration into the handler function, its value will not be preserved when the handler is called the following times - it is a new variable each time. Check it out by changing the position of the var declaration inside of the example.

Comment: It does **NOT** work, can you not see it continously logging "called traffic" even when "load" isn't entered? http://gyazo.com/23e57b65869340ff02e6aab55dc18811

Comment: @ConorReid weird. i see it in your screen shot, but not when trying it myself

Comment: @ConorReid remove the 'var' statement inside of the handler function. you are declaring a new variable of the same name 'trafficInterval' there.

Comment: @ConorReid I see it works now. Mind accepting an answer?

Comment: No. It's not fixed. My problem has not been solved, your solution has no affect what-so ever as it has the same problem.

Comment: @ConorReid That is very strange. I saw that you changed the code on your site and it, too works perfectly for me (using Chome latest). You seem to have another problem, good luck!